# @ModelAttribute return null thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I familiarize myself with *Thymeleaf*.

I am trying to get data from a POST-mapping in the controller.
But I got `null` variables when I call `employee.getName()`.

I looked a lot online but can't find a solution.

#### My controller class

```java
@GetMapping
public String getEmployees(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("newEmployee", new Employee());
    
    return "employees";
}

@PostMapping
public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("newEmployee") Employee employee) {
    System.out.println(employee); // return object
    System.out.println(employee.getFirstName()); // return null

    return "employees";
}
```

#### HTML  form with Thymeleaf

```html
<div class="modal-body">
    <form th:action="@{/employees}" th:object="${newEmployee}" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label">First Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <input th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: @mikebrucks: For debugging please add a [logging request-interceptor](http://www.javabyexamples.com/request-logging-using-spring-mvc/) and show us (a) the logging output, plus (b) your `Employee` class (incl. all getters/setters).

Comment: employee class have only getters is need to have setters I want to create new object employee from the data of the form

Comment: The form is open with JavaScript is dynamic, I don't know if it's important

Answer (score -1):

See tutorials:

- Wim Deblauwe: [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/)
- Baeldung: [Binding a List in Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list)

```java
@GetMapping("/all")
public String showAll(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employees", employeeService.findAll());
    return "employees/all";
}

@GetMapping("/add")
public String createForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("newEmployee", new Employee()); // the form-data object as blank employee to be filled

    return "employees/form";  // the page containing the form
}

@PostMapping
public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("newEmployee") Employee employee) {
    System.out.println(employee); // return object
    System.out.println(employee.getFirstName()); // return null if either not set in HTML-form or not mapped from HTML-form to POST correctly

     // save new employee or add to a repository
    employeeService.save(newEmployee);

    model.addAttribute("employees", employeeService.findAll());
    return "redirect:/employees/all";  // use a redirect
}
```

Client-Server interaction:

1. First in your browser you should navigate to the endpoint adding the form-data-object, i.e. `GET /employees/add`.
   Then the form-page should load and you will have a blank object `newEmployee` to bind all the input-fields to for submitting.
2. After submitting the form via the submit-click, a `POST /employees` is sent. The server/controller should receive the form-data as model-attribute in `employee` parameter and can save it.
3. The controller-method redirects back to the list-endpoint (same as navigating in browser to) `GET /employees/all`

```html
<h1>Create employee</h1>
<form th:object="${newEmployee}"
      th:action="@{/employees}"
      method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" />
    <button type="submit">Submit new employee</button>
</form>
```

- The `th:object` attribute refers to the key under which we put our `Employee` instance in the model (`newEmployee` in this example). The `th:action` has the URL for the `@PostMapping` method. Finally, the `method` attribute is set to `"post"` since we want to use the HTTP POST method.
- Using `th:field=*{…​}`, we can setup a **two-way binding** between the HTML input and the field in our form data object.

Comment: Still is not working

Comment: It's still not clear to me what is to blame for the behavior they see and what they need to change.

Comment: The Model Attribute is not valid it pass null object